# MySQL: Counting active products that belong to active categories (and optionally to active subcategories)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, mysql-5.6

i'm using **MySQL 5.6**. I need to get a list of categories, with a product `count` column. So far, a very easy and trivial task. Here's where it gets a little complicated:

- A product has a category, and can also have a subcategory (optionally).
- **Categories**, **subcategories** and **products** can be active (`flg_public=1`) or disabled (`flg_public=NULL`).

So, the query should return a list of categories with the product count, where these requirements are met:

- If a category is disabled, it must not appear in the list.
- If a category's subcategory is disabled, any products inside that subcategory should not be considered for the product count of the respective category.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT store_cat.id_cat AS id_cat, 
       store_cat.name AS name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT store_product.id_product) AS q 
FROM   store_cat 
       LEFT JOIN store_product 
              ON store_product.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
                 AND store_product.flg_public = 1 
       LEFT JOIN store_subcat 
              ON store_product.id_subcat = store_subcat.id_subcat 
                 AND store_subcat.flg_public = 1 
WHERE  store_cat.flg_public = 1 
GROUP  BY store_cat.id_cat
```

I've added a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43461b/1

In this example:

- The subcategory **Pants** belongs to the category **Clothes**.
- The subcategory **Pants** `id_subcat=6` has been disabled with `flg_public=0`
- The subcategory **Pants** has only 1 product which is active, but since the subcategory has been disabled, this 1 product should not be considered in the `count` query.
- As you can see, there are 4 products using `id_cat=1`, but one of those products is **Pantalon Flash** `id_product=47` which belongs to the subcategory **Pants** `id_subcat=6` which has been disabled... *but is still being considered in the count*...

The **Clothes** category is returning **4** in the amount column... but  it should be **3**. Here's what the results should display (changes in red):

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Show desired result for fiddle data 2) Specify MySQl version. 3) In your scheme the data may contradict (the product may refer to one subcategory directly and to another one via category) - how the product must be considered in this case?

Comment: @Akina 1) i added a screenshot with the correction in red color /// 2) i added the mysql version (5.6). /// 3) products can optionally have id_cat and id_subcat... the subcat can only be children of the selected category (this is controlled in the input form and was not normalized intentionally for other purposes).

Comment: Please look at the fiddle in my answer (especially intermediate non-grouped query). According to it - build the table `(store_product.flg_public, store_subcat.flg_public, 'matched or not')`. 9 lines - 0, 1, NULL for each `flg_public`, and matching value. This will allow to refine the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT store_cat.id_cat AS id_cat, 
       store_cat.name AS name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT store_product.id_product) AS q 
FROM   store_cat 
       LEFT JOIN store_product 
              ON store_product.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
--                 AND store_product.flg_public = 1 
       LEFT JOIN store_subcat 
              ON store_product.id_subcat = store_subcat.id_subcat 
--                 AND store_subcat.flg_public = 1 
WHERE  store_cat.flg_public = 1 
  AND COALESCE(store_subcat.flg_public, 1)
GROUP  BY store_cat.id_cat, store_cat.name ;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fc3fcdae85adf7882ff2816c25b24124)

Minimal explanations commented into the fiddle.

Comment: This seems to work fine, except for a specific case scenario. If a product has flg_public=NULL, it will still be counted in your query. Adding a `AND COALESCE(store_product.flg_public, 1)` should correct it, right?

Comment: @Nick I see `3` for `Snacks` on the screenshot in the question which is NOT marked red.

Comment: @AndresSK Please build the table I have asked in the comment to the question.

Comment: @Akina see OPs comment to my answer. The Snacks value in the question is incorrect.

Comment: Both answers are correct (of course once i added the extra COALESCE). Your query looks cleaner because of the COALESCE usage, thanks.

Comment: @Akina just one quick question, why do you do this `GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat, store_cat.name` instead of just `GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat`?

Comment: @AndresSK If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` server option is enabled then single `GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat` will cause error like *Expression #x of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY*. So either 2 fields in grouping expression or wrapping non-grouped field into some aggregate function (for example, MAX() or ANY_VALUE()) is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that because you `LEFT JOIN` to `store_subcat`, even products which have a subcategory with `flg_public = 0` get included in the output rows (try removing the `GROUP BY` and changing to a `SELECT *` and you will see that `Pantalon Flash` is in the output rows even though its fields from `store_subcat` are all `NULL` because it failed the `flg_public = 1` join condition). To work around that, you need to add a check that either that `store_product.id_subcat` is `NULL`, or that `store_subcat.id_subcat` is not `NULL` (which will be the case when a product has a subcategory which has `flg_public = 1`. The updated query:

```
SELECT store_cat.id_cat AS id_cat, 
       store_cat.name AS name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT store_product.id_product) AS q 
FROM store_cat 
LEFT JOIN store_product ON store_product.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
                       AND store_product.flg_public = 1 
LEFT JOIN store_subcat ON store_product.id_subcat = store_subcat.id_subcat 
                      AND store_subcat.flg_public = 1 
WHERE store_cat.flg_public = 1 
  AND (store_product.id_subcat IS NULL OR store_subcat.id_subcat IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat
```

Output:

```
id_cat  name        q
1       Clothes     3
2       Accesories  1
3       Snacks      2
4       Other       0
6       Furniture   0
7       Bags        0
9       Pencils     1
10      Medicines   0
11      Candy       0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43461b/24)

Note that the correct count for `Snacks` is actually 2, not 3. Of the 4 Snacks, `Cookie wrappers` has `flg_public = 0` so shouldn't be included, and `Pan de espárragos` has `id_subcat = 1` and that subcat has `flg_public = 0` so it shouldn't be included either. So of the 4 snacks, only 2 should be included.

Comment: @Akina that's because `2` is actually the correct answer. Of the 4 Snacks, `Cookie wrappers` has `flg_public = 0` so shouldn't be included, and `Pan de espárragos` has `id_subcat = 1` and that subcat has `flg_public = 0` so shouldn't be included. So of the 4 snacks, only 2 should be included.

Comment: @Nick you are correct, it was an error in my screenshot, I should've also changed Snacks amount from 3 to 2.